# Cocoapods and custom xcconfig

Tags: ios, cocoapods, xcconfig

I am trying to use Cocoapods with some custom configurations in an iOS project.
I have 3 (Dev, Stage, Prod) and each of them has some custom `GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS`.
I have seen around people suggesting to us `#include <path-to-pods.xcconfig>`, but this seems to the old way to do this.
I have seen Cocoapods `0.39` is automatically generating its config files based on my configurations and adding them to my targets automatically (and this is good).
This is also confirmed by [this article](https://christiantietze.de/posts/2015/10/cocoapods-custom-build-configuration/) who is talking about a "new way" to create Podfiles.
The problem is these files don't contain my configurations.
I was trying to use `xcodeproj` and `link_with`, but without success.
Does anyone know what is the correct way to deal with Cocoapods + custom xcconfig files?

Comment: Are you managing your own podspec or using a third party pod?

Comment: How is including the cocoapods xcconfig file from your own one the old way ? This seems the simplest solution to combine cocoa pods and custom config files. Did you ever find a better solution ?

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that CocoaPods is based on xcconfig files and sets the actual variables. But these values cannot be used in any way when the full configuration is in xcconfig files like:

```
#include "../Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Demo/Pods-Demo.debug.xcconfig"
GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS = ...
```

In this case `GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS` overwrites the previous value.

Here is the way to solve it:

1. Update the Podfile to re-define the `GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS` value with `PODS_` prefix on post_install:

   ```
   post_install do |installer|
       work_dir = Dir.pwd
       Dir.glob("Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Demo/*.xcconfig") do |xc_config_filename|
           full_path_name = "#{work_dir}/#{xc_config_filename}"
           xc_config = File.read(full_path_name)
           new_xc_config = new_xc_config.sub(/GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS/, 'PODS_GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS')
           File.open(full_path_name, 'w') { |file| file << new_xc_config }
       end

   end
   ```
2. Define xcconfig file in the next way:

   ```
   #include "../Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Demo/Pods-Demo.debug.xcconfig"
   GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS = $(PODS_GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS) ...
   ```

In this case `GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS` should contain `PODS_GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS` & you custom values.

Comment: It looks like the CocoaPods' `$(inherited)` is not picked up, so you actually have to use `GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS = $(inherited) $(PODS_GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS) ...`.